# Problems with android-pulltorefresh widget

Tags: java, android, listview

I am having a bit of difficulty implementing the android-pulltorefresh widget by Johan Nilsson found at https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

The problem I am having is after putting the custom listview into my application everything is fine it, but it asks to Tap to Refresh the list view but I need it to be set to pull down to refresh.

The code I am using below is pretty much from the github page and a screenshot of the app can be found below do demonstrate my issue:

```
PullToRefreshListView lv = (PullToRefreshListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
lv.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
    public void onRefresh() {
    // Do work to refresh the list here.
    GetData getData = new GetData();
    getData.execute();
}
```

[image]

I need the Tap to refresh header gone and only to be shown once the listview has been dragged down. I get the feeling I just need to change some sort of flag but I can't find where this would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to work around this. The entire control is built around the idea that the "Pull to Refresh" header is a normal listview item that gets hidden by scrolling the list upward. Unfortunately, when you have a very short list, the list cannot be scrolled upward to hide the first item cause there are not enough items in the list -- so the fallback is to show the first item (the header) as well and have it display "Tap to Refresh".

EDIT: One kludge you may be able to do is insert dummy blank items so the list has enough items to hide the top header list item.

Answer (score 0):

use this [code](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)

Hope it works for you.